# extracting inside of each square in image with python.

Tags: python, database, image, python-2.7, image-processing

I want to make a data base for hand writing digits for the language other than English. Samples of handwritten digits are scanned as image('pic.jpg'). The empty sheet of sample was in the format of the excel with square cells and then printed out. A table of Ten rows*Ten columns in each page.

The problem is I want to label each number and extract the info of the image for that number (the square which the number is written inside), to use and train the neural network, but how can I approach that in python?
So far I read the image, change it to black and white and save the black and white format('image2.jpg') as below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image
from scipy.misc import imsave

BW = cv2.imread('pic.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)#TO GET rid of alpha
#256/2 = 128 
BW[BW < 128]=0
BW[BW>=128]=255
imsave("image2.jpg",BW)
```

I also wanted to extract the table from image first and do the process on that next. I used another form and I did :

```
img =  cv2.imread('pic.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,1,1,11,2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`
```

but it gives me and error "ValueError: too many values to unpack", i don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

I myself am a total cv2 noob, but I also recently ran into this problem.  I was able to avoid it by changing this

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)
```

to something like

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(...)
```

I am not sure why this happens.  Again, I am pretty new to python and cv2.  This did fix my error, though.